# MATLAB tic/toc in called function

Tags: matlab, timer

In MATLAB, I want to time a function written by someone else, and their function might use `tic`/`toc` internally. I want my own `tic`/`toc`. But if the inner function calls `tic`, then the outer timer gets reset.

How can I avoid this? I don't want to use `timeit` because `timeit` will call the inner function multiple times, which I don't want.

MWE:

*Outer script:*

```
tic

inner_function()

elapsed_time = toc;

fprintf('Function took %f seconds\n', elapsed_time)
```

*Inner function:*

```
function [] = inner_function()

    pause(2)

    tic
    toc

end
```

Then:

```
>> outer_script
Elapsed time is 0.000024 seconds.
Function took 0.000232 seconds
```

If you comment out the `tic`/`toc` in `inner_function()` you get this, which is what I want:

```
>> outer_script
Function took 2.000362 seconds
```

Just for a little more context, the outer script is mine, and I use it to test functions written by my students. I want to allow them to use `tic`/`toc` however they want in their code, but I also want to be able to time their code independently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by assigning your `tic` calls to a variable. Give your desired timer to `toc` later on as an argument.

```
function [] = inner_function()    
    pause(2)    
    tic
    toc    
end
```

Rerunning a modified example,

```
clock2 = tic;
inner_function()
elapsed_time = toc(clock2);
fprintf('Function took %f seconds\n', elapsed_time)
Elapsed time is 0.000009 seconds.
Function took 2.009997 seconds
```

Comment: But I don’t want to require the person writing the inner function to do this. In other words, I want a solution that works even if the inner function calls tic and toc without assigning them to variables.

Comment: Yep, I misunderstood your question. I made the appropriate edits to the answer.